# Swift TextField Parameter

Tags: swift, textfield

Hello i just started learning swift,I'm trying to create a function

```
func dataStoroge(dataStoreName:UITextField,dataStoregaForKey:String,forEntityName:String) {
    let appDelegate=UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context=appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let newUser=NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: forEntityName, into: context)
    
    newUser.setValue(dataStoreName, forKey: dataStoregaForKey)
    
    
    
    do {
        
        try context.save()
        print("success")
    }
    catch{
        print("error")
    }
    
    
}
```

below is where i use the function

```
let newUser=dataProcessors()
    newUser.dataStoroge(dataStoreName: mailTextField, dataStoregaForKey: "mail", forEntityName: "UserInformation")
```

I want to get the data from the textfield but I don't know which parameter to use. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean `dataStoreName.text`?

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot. Is there any mistake in the code that you notice?